# Getting average or keeping temp data in db - performance concern

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am building a little app for users to create collections. I want to have a rating system in there. And now, since I want to cover all my fields, let's pretend that I have a lot of visitors. Performance comes into play, especially with rates.

Let's suppose that I have `rates` table, and there I have `id`, `game_id`, `user_id` and `rate`. Data comes simple, for every user there is one entry. Let's suppose again, that 1000 users will rate one game. And I want to print out average rate on that game subpage (and somewhere else, like on the games list). For now, I have two scenarios to go with:

1. Getting `AVG` each time the game is displayed.
2. Creating another column in `games`, called `temprate` and store there rate for the game. It would be updated evey time someone votes.

Those two scenarios have obvious flaws. First one is more stressful to my host, since it definietly will consume more power of the machine. Secound is more work while rating (getting all the game data, submitting rate, getting new `AVG`).

Please advice me, which scenario should I go with? Or maybe you have some other ideas?

I work with PDO and no framework.

Comment: (3) keep the average in a cache like memcache.

Comment: Somewhat related question -- can a user rate a given game more than once?

Comment: Wrikken - memcache looks really, really nice. Can you give me some more details (something straightforward, without taking a deep dive into the docs)? I'm still thinking about a way to go.

Girish Rao - yes and no. User can change his vote, which will be treated like an update, not a new record.

Comment: It seems that memcached isn't available at my host. Any other ideas?

Comment: Aside from the obvious (_"Switch hosts? Use a VPS?"_), any cache would do... APC perhaps, or even (the horror!) filebased, or... as you say, in your database. Almost anything is better then rerererecalculating everything every single time.

Comment: This is a personal project, so I can't afford a really good host nor a VPS :( I'll try to find some good caching solution for PDO. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've finally manage to solve this issue. I used file caching based on dumping arrays into files. I just go with something like `if (cache) { $var = cache } else { $var = db }`. I am using [JG Cache](https://github.com/jonknee/JG_Cache), for now, but propably I'll write myself something similar soon, but for now - it's a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have gone with a variation of your "number 2" solution (update a separate rating column), maybe in a separate table just for this.

If the number of writes becomes a problem, then that'd be well after `select avg(foo) from ...` does, and there are lots of ways to mitigate it by just updating the average rating periodically or just processing new votes every so often.

Likely then eventually you can't just do an avg() anyway because you have to consider each vote for fraud, [calculating a sort score](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) and who knows what else.,

Comment: Thanks for great resource! I never thought of considering votes as fraud, since I only have "positive" ones. Or should I asume that "positive" are only 5-10 and "negatives" are 1-5?

Comment: It really depends on your users and things being "voted".  Often the votes will all fall in 1-2 or 7-10 (if you thought something was a 5, why vote?).   It also depends on what you are trying to measure.  For example if you are making a recommendation engine and looking for input for that, then maybe everything 5 or better might be good enough to indicate the user (sorta mostly maybe) liked it.